# log message in custom nifi processor not showing in testing

Tags: apache-nifi

I am developing my custom processor for Apache NIFI.

Basically, my processor is fine. But the problem is that when I test it, the debug messages does not show. Only the info message shows.

How do I fix this problem?

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.fet.processors.mdms.SampleProcessor - SampleProcessor[id=12c89263-c3a3-4758-977b-64a7593e103c] BEGIN to TEST XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Below is the way I run TestSampleProcessor:

[image]

SampleProcessor:

```java
    import org.helper.FlowFileHelper;
    import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.*;
    import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.*;
    import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
    import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
    import org.apache.nifi.logging.ComponentLog;
    import org.apache.nifi.processor.*;

    
    @Tags(["Test logger message"])
    @CapabilityDescription("Sample processor for testing log message")
    @SeeAlso([])
    @ReadsAttributes([@ReadsAttribute(attribute="", description="")])
    @WritesAttributes([@WritesAttribute(attribute="", description="")])
    public class SampleProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
        public static final Relationship REL_SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
                .name("success")
                .description("Test logger message")
                .build();
        private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<>();
    
        private Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<>();
        private ComponentLog log;
    
        @Override
        protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
    
            log = getLogger();
            relationships.add(MY_RELATIONSHIP);
            relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
        }
    
        @Override
        public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
            return this.relationships;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) {
            FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
            if (flowFile == null) return;
            String content   = FlowFileHelper.readFlowfileContent(flowFile, session);
            log.info("BEGIN to TEST XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            log.debug("TEST =================================");
            log.debug("content is {}", content);
            session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
```

src/main/resources/logback.xml

```xml
    <configuration>
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{5}.%method:%line - %message%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    
        <logger name="org.apache.nifi" level="WARN">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
    
        <logger name="com.fet.processors" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
    
        <root level="WARN">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

My test code:

```
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunner
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunners
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class TestSampleProcessor {
    private TestRunner testRunner;
    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(SampleProcessor.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogDebugMessage() {
        testRunner.enqueue("This is data of flowfile");
        testRunner.run();
    }
}
```

src/test/resources/logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{5}.%method:%line - %message%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache.nifi" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.fet.processors" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't see in your log sample format that corresponds pattern `...logger{5}.%method:%line`

Comment: @daggett It could be that org.junit.jupiter doesn't use logback.xml, does it? I run TestSampleProcessor in IntelliJ-IDEA by clicking TestSampleProcessor in left "Project" window and clicking "Run  TestSampleProcessor" in the pop-up menu. I am not sure whether it matters. Anyway, I just update the snapshot in above

Answer (score 0):

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration

2. If no custom Configurator was found in the previous step, then DefaultJoranConfigurator will be instantiated and invoked.

   • If the system property "logback.configurationFile" is set, then DefaultJoranConfigurator will try to locate the file specified the aforementioned system property.

   • If the previous step fails, DefaultJoranConfigurator will try to locate the configuration file logback-test.xml in the classpath.

   • If no such file is found, it will try to locate the configuration file logback.xml in the classpath. Note that this is the nominal configuration step.

   • If neither file can be located, DefaultJoranConfigurator will return without further processing.
3. If none of the above succeeds, logback-classic will configure itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.

so, i bet you are falling to step #3

---

to fix it try to set path to file with"logback.configurationFile" system property. or make sure your `logback.xml` is in classpath.